# D3: x-axis with time interval of a year

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am new to d3 and html and unable to figure out if it something wrong with the d3javascript part or the html part that nothing is displayed on running the scripts. I am trying to display x-axis with interval of a year. following is the d3 bit.

```
var w = 940,
    h = 300,
    pad =20,
    left_pad =100,
    data_set = [[20/02/1993],
                [05/03/1994],
                [14/09/1994],
                [23/04/1992],
                [27/05/1993],
                [15/11/1992],
                [14/04/1994]
                ];      


var svg= d3.select("#punchcard")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

var xMin = d3.min(data_set, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.date; }); });
var xMax = d3.max(data_set, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.date; }); });

var xAxisScale = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, w])
                .domain([xMin, xMax]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xAxisScale)
            .ticks(d3.time.year, 1)
            .orient("bottom");

var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0, "+(h-pad)+")")
                .call(xAxis);
```

and the html bit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #eee;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.loading {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.circle {
    fill: #222;
}
</style>


<div id="punchcard"></div>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this does what you think it does:

```
 var data_set = [[20/02/1993],
                [05/03/1994],
                [14/09/1994],
                [23/04/1992],
                [27/05/1993],
                [15/11/1992],
                [14/04/1994]
                ];
```

This will make `data_set` =

```
[ [ 0.005017561465127948 ],
  [ 0.0008358408559010365 ],
  [ 0.0007801181321743007 ],
  [ 0.0028865461847389557 ],
  [ 0.002709483191169092 ],
  [ 0.0006845564074479737 ],
  [ 0.0017552657973921766 ] ]
```

Because the '/' will be parsed as division operator.

What you probably want is the following:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y');
var data_set = [[dateFormat.parse('20/02/1993')],
                [dateFormat.parse('05/03/1994')],
                [dateFormat.parse('14/09/1994')],
                [dateFormat.parse('23/04/1992')],
                [dateFormat.parse('27/05/1993')],
                [dateFormat.parse('15/11/1992')],
                [dateFormat.parse('14/04/1994')]
                ];
```

**Update:**

Actually, there are more changes to the data needed, looking at how you are extracting `xMin` and `xMax` from the `data_set`.

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y');
var data_set = [{ values: [{ date: dateFormat.parse('20/02/1993') }] },
                { values: [{ date: dateFormat.parse('05/03/1994') }] },
                { values: [{ date: dateFormat.parse('14/09/1994') }] },
                { values: [{ date: dateFormat.parse('23/04/1992') }] },
                { values: [{ date: dateFormat.parse('27/05/1993') }] },
                { values: [{ date: dateFormat.parse('15/11/1992') }] },
                { values: [{ date: dateFormat.parse('14/04/1994') }] }
               ];
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QvyvxyNsCthrRO3i0zBq?p=preview

Comment: It still doesn't work. All I get is a blank screen :(

Comment: I have copied ur files and tried running, it still doesn't come up with anything for me. I am using DreamWeaver and I use the "Preview/Debug in browser" button to display the contents but nothing comes up. I tried Safari, Google Chrome, Firefox, but all failed :(

Comment: It's something to do with the dreamweaver apparently. I copied the files in TextEdit and ran them and it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help.